# How to preserve color / text formatting across cells when using concatenate in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if someone here may be able to offer me some advice or help on how to achieve the following in a Google sheet:

I have 4 columns in my Google sheet that I use 'concatenate' with (so the contents of each row from the 4 columns shows in a single cell at the end of that row).

I have 2 columns that are a different color font to the others.

I would like to preserve the formatting of the font color if that's possible, as it will save me a lot of work when copying and pasting that final cell into a text report.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance.

/g

Answer (score 0):

At this time it's not possible to preserve the formatting of the font color of cell values taht are being concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

this is an annoying thing. I had some similar problem that i could solve.
It is not exactly the same, but since there is no other solution to your problem. I tell mine in case is useful.

I'm not concatenating, but similar, i have several cells(for example 4) in a column, with rich format, different colors (for more info, it is a cheat sheet of code for python, conserving the colors when it is written in pyCharm).
I want this several cells in one only cell, but preserving the colors!

As Ruben said, is not a direct solution, but in my case there is an indirect solution.
I copy paste in word, conserve the color, cool

delete the line break, so the 4 cells is now in only one line in word

copy paste in excel, conserve the color, cool

open the excel with google drive, open as a google sheet now

good, the 4 cells there is now in one cell and all the color are conserved

if you put the line break now, colors are conserved.

As a conclusion, if the text in cell A1 is blue, and text in cell A2 is red
if you copy paste text A2 inside cell A1 (enter editing cell A1, below text already A1 enter:new break line, copy paste new text) color is not conserved, no way, no especial paste, no nothing.
But if as i described you get the text with different colors in the same line of the same cell, when put a line break, color is not lose

I lot a work, i know, don't kill the messenger...
I only do this for important docs where i want perfect format, a cheat sheet is important to me so...